# What is the purpose of $connect in mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $username)?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

So I was wondering, if I need to escape a string, why do I need to connect to my database first?

I tried something like:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
```

But that didn't work, it requires 2 parameters(one of which is the $connect) Could y ou please explain the purpose of connecting to the database first and then escaping it?

I would also like to know how would that be efficient/applied in a registration page as well?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a real question: this information is available in the PHP manual.

Comment: The documentation for that function says quite plainly: "*The given string is encoded to an escaped SQL string, **taking into account the current character set of the connection**.*" Different connection charsets need different encodings.

Comment: I recommend [not using *_escape_string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2864740) if possible.

Comment: Read the manual next time before asking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php):

> Security: the default character set
>
> The character set must be set either at the server level, or with the API function mysqli_set_charset() for it to affect mysqli_real_escape_string(). See the concepts section on character sets for more information.

And therein lies the reason for having the connection: how to escape your string depends on the server's character set.